# How to add "Build path" option in Eclipse, when clicking on a project with right button?

Tags: eclipse

As in a topic. I can not find solution, how to add that option to right button list.

Answer (score 6):

In the Toolbar Menu, click on "Window->Show View->Package Explorer.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Silly me, I was looking in Navigator for that option :)

Answer (score 4):

It was a problem of mine too. Have you tried:

1. Right click on the project's name.
2. Click Properties.
3. Click Java Build Path that appear on the menu to the left.
4. From the buttons that appear on the right, click Add External JARs.
5. From the window that appears, find the jar file(s) that you want to add and then click open. It should be done now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that your project (.project file in your project's root directory) includes the Java Nature and build spec, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>project_1_x</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: I just have checked .project file and it includes all entries U wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the project -> Search Project Facets -> Convert to faceted project -> Enable the builder (ex. Java)

Comment: This worked for me and I am able to see the Build Path option now as before I was not able to find anything related to the build path in the properties.